# Adding Tables Rows and Cells Dynamically Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html-table, ecmascript-5, onsubmit

I was trying to add a table row with data in my HTML table using Javascript but it seems I it can't add. Why is that?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
  </title>
   <script>
    function addUser(){
        var tbl = document.getElementById('datatable');
        var lastRow  = tbl.rows.length;

        var iteration = lastRow+1;
        var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

        var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
        cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);     
    }
   </script>
 </head>
  <body>
    <table border = 1 id = "datatable">
        <tr>
         <td>ID</td>
         <td>NAME</td>
         <td>ADDRESS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>Something</td>
         <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>Foo</td>
         <td>bar</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <form id = "myForm" onsubmit = "addUser()">
    ID:<input type = "text" name = "txtID"><br />
    NAME:<input type = "text" name = "txtName"><br />
    ADDRESS:<input type = "text" name = "txtAddress"><br />
    <input type = "submit" value = "Add Item">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know how to see errors, I am using google chrome

Comment: ctrl-shift-j shows the javascript console

Answer (score 2):

what you need is not to submit a form 
just simply an onclick event could help.

```
<input type = "button" value = "Add Item" onclick="addUser()">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're submiyting a form. First your AddUSer is called and works, but the page is reloaded and what you see is the initial page.